# Android: How to make Swipe screen Navigation comfortable

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe, gesture-recognition, gesturedetector

I am using Gesture Listner to acheive Swipe screen navigation. But it is not so comfortable that I need to swipe multiple time to navigate to next or previous screen.  What are the proper values for Velocity, Off path and Min Distance.

Please find below is my code:

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 300;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                viewFlipper.showNext();    
                configDisplay();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                configDisplay();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this which  [calculates][1] the values based on DisplayMetrics



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection/5039732#5039732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links helped me achieve the solution:

[GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

[implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gestur](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)

[Android-pinch](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/)

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented an app that used flinging and started out with *SimpleOnGestureListener* just like your example. I logged velocity and offset on each fling and tested on my device to find what I thought was suitable values.

**But** - I highly recommend you to take a look at the *ViewPager* which is available in the [compability package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) instead.

[About ViewPager with link to example.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)